# I want to display all the products related to one particular shop in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

> Views.py

```
    matching_product = Product.objects.filter(shop__shop_slug=single_slug)
    return render(request, 'products/shop_products.html',{"part_ones":matching_product})
```

> urls.py

`path("<single_slug>",views.single_slug, name="single_slug")`

> shop_products

`{% for shops in matching_product %}`

> shop.html (for url)
>   `<a href="{{shop.shop_slug}}"><strong>{{shop.shop_location}}</strong></a>`

**It is not displaying any products**

Answer (score 0):

matching_product = Product.objects.filter(shop__shop_slug=single_slug)

First, debug the line above. is there any result?